# IRSSI screen_away.py script refuses to work

Tags: irssi

I am using the screen_away.py script in IRSSI and it just refuses to work. I have tried restarting, reloading and I'm stuck...

any help?!

Comment: Please explain "refuses to work".

Comment: is it because it's a perl script that's labeled .py? or are you running irssi-python?

Answer (score 0):

Just to confirm... you are doing...

```
screen
irssi
/script load screen_away.pl

C-a d
```

That is... you've started an irssi session inside a screen session, loaded the script then disconnected from the screen.

And then how are you confirming whether it worked?

It doesn't "just work" if you start irssi without it being inside screen.